# Pickle vs output to a file in python

Tags: python, file-io, pickle

I have a program that outputs some lists that I want to store to work with later. For example, suppose it outputs a list of student names and another list of their midterm scores. I can store this output in the following two ways:

Standard File Output way:

```
newFile = open('trialWrite1.py','w')
newFile.write(str(firstNames))
newFile.write(str(midterm1Scores))
newFile.close()
```

The pickle way:

```
newFile = open('trialWrite2.txt','w')
cPickle.dump(firstNames, newFile)
cPickle.dump(midterm1Scores, newFile)
newFile.close()
```

Which technique is better or preferred? Is there an advantage of using one over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module might be a good fit here, since CSV is a standard format that can be both read and written by Python (and many other languages), and it's also human-readable. Usage could be as simple as

```
with open('trialWrite1.py','wb') as fileobj:
    newFile = csv.writer(fileobj)
    newFile.writerow(firstNames)
    newFile.writerow(midterm1Scores)
```

However, it'd probably make more sense to write one student per row, including their name and score. That can be done like this:

```
from itertools import izip
with open('trialWrite1.py','wb') as fileobj:
    newFile = csv.writer(fileobj)
    for row in izip(firstNames, midterm1Scores):
        newFile.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I think `writerow` expects a tuple not a stringified collection.

Comment: According to the documentation, it'll take any sequence, including lists or tuples.

Comment: If I use the line `newFile.close()`, I get an error saying that " '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'close' "

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: For some reason I thought you'd passed it `str( firstNames )`. Maybe you edited before I saw it :/? @Curious2learn: close the file, not the writer.

Comment: @katrielalex: ah yes, you probably saw it before I'd edited. I had copied from the question and I forgot to fix that part at first.

Comment: @Curious2learn: sorry about that, I always forget that CSV writers don't have `close` methods. I've edited the code and I think it should work now. The new way uses the `with` statement available in Python 2.6+ that automatically closes the file at the end of the block.

Answer (score 3):

`pickle` is more generic -- it allows you to dump many different kinds of objects to a file for later use. The downside is that the interim storage is not very human-readable, and not in a standard format.

Writing strings to a file, on the other hand, is a much better interface to other activities or code. But it comes at the cost of having to parse the text back into your Python object again.

Both are fine for this simple (list?) data; I would use `write( firstNames )` simply because there's no need to use pickle. In general, how to persist your data to the filesystem depends on the data!

---

For instance, `pickle` will happily pickle functions, which you can't do by simply writing the string representations.

```
>>> data = range
<class 'range'>
>>> pickle.dump( data, foo )
# stuff
>>> pickle.load( open( ..., "rb" ) )
<class 'range'.
```

Comment: `pickle` doesn't exactly pickle functions & classes like you might assume - (http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) "Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully qualified” name reference, not by value..."  Persistence in this case relies on stable module hierarchies and interfaces since the unpickling environment must match the pickling environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will either write the string representation or use CSV as David has suggested.

Comment: @Jeremy: I didn't realise `pickle` didn't like user-defined functions -- thanks!

Comment: pickle only really doesn't like functions & classes defined within other functions/classes. It's not something specific to user-defined functions. The idea is that it serializes an import path that needs to be valid when you unpickle the function reference (that's the trick it uses - it imports the module that contained the top-level function/class definition).  The potential problems come from: 1. You share the objects with other programs (like using it for client/server comm) 2. You use it for persistence and then remove functions/change class methods in a code update.

Answer (score 0):

For a completely different approach, consider that [Python ships with SQLite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html). You could store your data in a SQL database without adding any third-party dependencies.

Comment: I need to use the data to plot graphs with matplotlib. I could import from SQlite but that seems too much work to export and import it.